# Capture clicks on a Sencha chart label

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-charts

Since I'm updating my application from Ext JS 4.2.1 to Ext JS 5.1, I took the chance to upgrade my old charts to the shiny new sencha charts. I've been trying to set up an interactable stacked bar chart that looks like this

[image: Chart]

Users should be able to click on the bars or on the labels on the left to check out the details.

I've managed to capture mouse events on the chart bars (using the `chartitemevents` plugin), but I'm stuck trying to capture click events on the labels.

I've tried using the `spriteevents` plugin on the chart, but on 5.1 it simply doesn't work, and it's broken on the 5.1.1 nightly builds (you always get the background sprite no matter what). Even if it did work, getting the correct sprite would only get me halfway there as I would have no clue about which series does that label belong to.

Here's a fiddle with an example of the situation: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hjm

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

As and added bonus, it would be great if it was possible to capture onmouseover and onmouseout events too, so I could change the cursor to pointer whenever a label is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

i just created a plugin for axis click: [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?298267-Chart-axis-click)

Ask me anything if the plugin usage is not clear.